# MoviePi on Pi 3: Unable to install

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to install MoviePy on Raspberry Pi 3? I've tried using following commands, but didn't get success.

**(sudo) pip install moviepy**

**(sudo) pip install ez_setup**

-> Could not find any downloads that satisfy requirement moviepy

**(sudo) python setup.py install**

->python: can't open file 'setup.py':[Errno 2] no such file or directory

Please help

Comment: Try running `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`, sometimes updating pip is all it takes.

Answer (score 1):

You must execute `python setup.py install` in an extracted source distribution of the package.
You must execute `pip` while you have an internet connection.
If you don't have the requirements of moviepy, `python setup.py install` also requires an internet connection.